# Testing if binary tree is balanced in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, tree, binary-tree

what is another way to test whether a binary tree is balanced other than recursively calling the size function on the left and right subtrees. abs(size left - size right) <= 1 for the tree to be balanced. I must write an efficient function to satisfy the requirement but like i said does not recursively call the size function on the left and right subtrees.

Comment: How is your binary tree represented?

Answer (score 2):

So it's pretty easy with recursion, isn't it?

```
import Data.Maybe (isJust)

getBalancedSize :: (Monad m, Num b, Ord b) => BinaryTree a -> m b
getBalancedSize Empty = return 0
getBalancedSize (Node _ l r) = do
    sizeL <- getBalancedSize l
    sizeR <- getBalancedSize r
    if abs (sizeL - sizeR) <= 1
        then return $ sizeL + sizeR + 1
        else fail "tree is not balanced"

isBalanced :: BinaryTree a -> Bool
isBalanced = isJust . getBalancedSize
```

Now suppose you have

```
fold :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
fold _ b Empty = b
fold f b (Node a l r) = f a (fold f b l) (fold f b r)
```

There's an obvious way to refactor `getBalancedSize` to be a single call to `fold`.

```
getBalancedSize = fold f (return 0) where
    f _ l r = do
        sizeL <- getBalancedSize l
        sizeR <- getBalancedSize r
        if abs (sizeL - sizeR) <= 1
            then return $ sizeL + sizeR + 1
            else fail "tree is not balanced"
```

But you do need *some* recursive function to walk the recursive tree structure.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your binary tree is represented in Haskell. If it's a recursive data structure, recursion is your only weapon...

Comment: well this is the way it is defined:                                  data BinaryTree a = Empty | Node a (BinaryTree a) (BinaryTree a)

Comment: There is no other way of descending down the tree except recursion in this case then.

Comment: alright thanks. I was trying everything to figure it out but i couldn't ever get anything that was quite right. I assumed there was another way since it was a question on my homework. I found the right answer using recursion but could fulfill the requirement of a balanced binary search tree using any other method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a type guaranteed [Red-Black Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree). No need to check if it is balanced because the types assure it.

```
isBalanced = const True
```

Comment: Encoding red-black invariants in the types and then actually working with the trees is possible, but not at all easy. You'd surely be better off with 2-3 trees, 2-3-4 trees, or AVL trees if you want to get all typey. Lots of code, but more uniform structure.

Comment: Red-black isn't too complicated. In my attempts at https://github.com/yairchu/red-black-tree the resulting code for red-black was shorter than for AVL.

Comment: Huh. I'm surprised. The papers I saw on red-black ran into complications affecting efficiency in significant ways, as I recall.

Comment: @dfeuer: Haven't benchmarked for efficiency. There might be other more efficient trees, I don't know..

Answer (score 0):

You could define a new binary tree that stores it's depth.  Depth is updated on insert and removal, and you can tell if it's balanced by looking at the stored depth value.

It is a nicer solution to calculate recursively depending on how often you are updating the tree.  It's cleaner anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The point about *efficiently* determining whether a tree is balanced without paying attention to its *size*, is that once you know the right branch is more than one level deeper than the left branch, it doesn't matter exactly how much deeper it is. 2 levels deeper? 3? 100? We don't care, and it could be considered inefficient to find out only to throw away the result.

```
isBalanced :: BinaryTree a -> Bool
isBalanced = and . treeToBalanceSize

treeToBalanceSize :: BinaryTree a -> BalanceSize
treeToBalanceSize Empty      = []
treeToBalanceSize (Node l r) = True : mergeBalanceSizes (treeToBalanceSize l) (treeToBalanceSize r)

mergeBalanceSizes :: BalanceSize -> BalanceSize -> BalanceSize
mergeBalanceSizes []       []       = []
mergeBalanceSizes [x]      []       = [x]
mergeBalanceSizes []       [y]      = [y]
mergeBalanceSizes (x : xs) (y : ys) = (x && y) : mergeBalanceSizes xs ys
mergeBalanceSizes _        _        = [False]

type BalanceSize = [Bool]
```

Satisfy yourself that

1. If `tree` is balanced and of size `size`, then `treeToBalanceSize tree = replicate size True`.
2. If `tree` is unbalanced, then `treeToBalanceSize tree` will end with a `False`.
3. Evaluating `mergeBalanceSizes [True] list` does not cause `list` to be evaluated beyond its third element.